# My output is assuming the whole file is one line

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
{       
    String inputFileName = "textfile.txt";

    printFileStats(inputFileName);
}
public static void printFileStats(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    String outputFileName = "outputtextfile.txt";
    File inputFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);

    int lines = 0;
    int words = 0;
    int characters = 0;

    while(in.hasNextLine())
    {               
        lines++;    
        while(in.hasNext())
        {
            in.next();
            words++;
        }   
    }

    out.println("Lines: " + lines);
    out.println("Words: " + words);
    out.println("Characters: " + characters);

    in.close();
    out.close();

}
```

I have a text file containing five lines

```
this is  
a text  
file  
full of stuff  
and lines
```

The code creates an output file

```
Lines: 1  
Words: 10 
Characters: 0
```

However, if I remove the capability for reading the number of words in the file, it correctly states the number of lines (5). Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your inner `while` loop is gobbling up the whole file. You want to count the number of words in each line, right? Try this instead:

```
while (in.hasNextLine())
{               
    lines++;    
    String line = in.nextLine();
    for (String word : line.split("\\s")) 
    {
        words++;
    }   
}
```

Note that splitting on spaces is a very naive approach to tokenization (word-splitting) and will only work for simple examples like the one you have here.

Of course, you could also do `words += line.split("\\s").length;` instead of that inner loop.

Comment: Care to explain what that does, exactly?  I'll research somewhere else if that's too much trouble, but I'd really appreciate it! I want to fully understand code that I'm injecting into my program.

What is "\\s"?

Comment: Before, you were only checking to see if your input *had* a new word/line. What I'm doing here is actually *reading* the line into a variable (`String line = in.nextLine();`), then I'm splitting that `String` into an array of smaller `String`s/words (assuming that words are separated by spaces, which in this case they are). Once I have an array of words, I can just see how long it is in order to see how many words were in that line, then I move on to the next line.

Comment: Ah, just saw your edit. `"\\s"` is a regular expression that means "any whitespace character". There's a learning curve to regular expressions (regexes), but as you get into programming; you'll find them very useful/sometimes necessary. They're worth a Google; I like [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for overview information.

Answer (score 1):

`in.hasNext()` and `in.next()` treat all whitespace characters as word separators, **including newline characters**. Your inner loop is eating all the newlines as it's counting all the words.

Answer (score 0):

This reads next `Token`, not the line :

```
in.next();
```

So it just read next and next and next and dont care about line ending. Space or `\n` is considered as `white space` usually, so methods like this one does not make any difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is, that `hasNext()` does not care about line breaks.

So, you are entering the `while(in.hasNextLine())` loop, but then you are consuming the whole file with the `while(in.hasNext())` loop, resulting in 1 line and 10 words.

-> Check the token consumed by `hasNext()` for EOL-Characters, then increase line count.

OR:

Use `String line = scanner.nextLine()` to obtain exactly ONE line, and then use a second scanner to fetch all tokens of that line: `scanner2 = new Scanner(line); while(scanner2.hasNext())`